# Conditions on subgroups $H, K$ of an abelian group $G$ such that $G/K \cong H/(H \cap K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups

I am trying to prove the equivalence of two formulations of simplicial homology on a manifold $X$, both of which are defined as the quotient of a certain set of simplicial chains on $X$ by a certain subset of chains that should intuitively equal zero. The problem reduces to showing that $G/K \cong H/(H \cap K)$, where $G$ is an abelian group of chains on $X$ with a large set of possible simplicial carriers, $H \subset G$ the subgroup of chains that include only one simplicial carrier (in two possible orientations, giving the usual singular homology), and $K \subset G$ the group of chains that should intuitively equal zero.

Is there a convenient condition on the subgroups $H, K$ that guarantees $G/K \cong H/(H \cap K)$? An obvious counterexample is given whenever $H = K \neq G$, but other "easy" examples seem to work: for example, $G = \mathbf{Z}$, $H = 2\mathbf{Z}$, and $K = 3\mathbf{Z}$; then $H/(H \cap K) = 3\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z} \cong \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the second isomorphism theorem, the condition that $HK=G$, or probably in your case $H+K=G$ (if we're using additive notation) is sufficient.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.